# MYSQL query error #1452

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, magento-1.9

I was trying to upload my Localhost website to the live server. In order to that i was uploading the .sql file for the database but my import was not successful instead it was showing the #1452 MySQL error.

I have tried

1. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
2. uploaded .SQL file again for new database
3. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

I don't know whether this solved my problem or not. Please help me to solve this error.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: @JayBlanchard according to that question it was related to the some department and employee table and i m getting this error when i m uploading database file from localhost phpmyadmin to live server phpadmin.

Comment: There are multiple duplicates for your question. Please find and read them all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I just have to run this command ? How will i know it solved that error.